# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в этой фразе?

Tags: пунктуация

Когда в голове возникает вопрос: с чего начать? Ответ можно дать очень простой – Вы уже начали.

Answer (score 1):

Без формулировок (о чем спрашиваем, что отвечаем) предложение выглядит так:
*Когда в голове возникает вопрос, ответ можно дать очень простой.*

1. Собственно прямая речь:
   **Когда в голове возникает вопрос: "С чего начать?" — ответ можно дать очень простой: "Вы уже начали".**
   (Тире после вопросительного знака, которым заканчивается прямая речь.)
2. Прямая речь (формулировка вопроса) включена в предложение в качестве его члена:
   **Когда в голове возникает вопрос "С чего начать?", ответ можно дать очень простой: "Вы уже начали".**

[**Прямая речь внутри слов автора**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=275#pp275)

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов много. Я бы предпочел вариант без кавычек, так как здесь не стоит задача дословно передать вопрос и ответ.

**Когда в голове возникает вопрос, с чего начать, ответ можно дать очень простой: вы уже начали.**

Такой стиль преобладает в публицистике.

> Поэтому на вопрос, с чего начать, я скажу словами Библии: время разбрасывать камни и время их собирать. [1. ЧТО НАМ ДАЛИ 10 ЛЕТ РЫНОЧНОЙ ЭКОНОМИКИ? 2. ЧТО БЫ ВЫ ПОСОВЕТОВАЛИ НЫНЕШНЕМУ ПРАВИТЕЛЬСТВУ? // Труд-7, 2000.10.02]
>
> Ответ прост, как все гениальное: человек как саморегулирующаяся система имеет некий встроенный механизм, ключ к лучшей жизни. [Яна Лан. Ключ к прозрению // «Психология на каждый день», 2011]

Answer (score 1):

**Когда в голове возникает вопрос, с чего начать,  то ответ можно дать очень простой: вы уже начали.**

Пример: Кстати, сам Дарвин ― а он был верующим человеком, ― когда ему задавали вопрос, **с чего все началось,** отвечал: **это не ко мне вопрос.** [Игорь Харичев, Сергей Дземешкевич. О сердце и не только // «Знание - сила», 2011]

Comment: Вы добавили *то*. Почему?

Comment: Я хотела  обозначить границу между группами предложений, а то общая структура  синтаксической конструкции плохо видна при беглом прочтении.